# sed substitutions within captured group

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I think that I'm missing something obvious, but I've spent a lot of time Googling around and searching stackoverflow, and I can't find an answer. I'm looking for a way to perform an additional sed substitution on a captured group. So, for example, if I have the text:

```
MD5 (./x y.jpg) = 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270
MD5 (./x y z.jpg) = 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270
```

I'd like to replace the spaces within the parentheses with underscores and reformat the string to be the filenamemd5.

```
./x_y.jpg 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270
./x_y_z.jpg 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270
```

I'm able to capture the filename, but I don't know how to perform another substitution on the captured group.

`echo 'MD5 (./x y.jpg) = 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270' | sed 's/MD5 (\(.*\)) = \(.*\)/\1 \2/'`

outputs:

`./x y.jpg 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` allows you to perform multiple substitutions (`s/.../.../`) in sequence, with each operating on the result of the previous:

```
echo 'MD5 (./x y.jpg) = 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270' |
 sed 's/MD5 (\(.*\)) = \(.*\)/\1|\2/; s/ /_/g; s/|/ /'
```

Here I've used a simple trick:

- 1st `s` command: I've used a `|` to temporarily separate the 2 backreferences.
- 2nd `s`: I then replace ALL spaces with `_` chars.
- 3rd `s`: I replace the `|` with a space, so that a single space remains.

Of course, this trick only works if your input data never contains `|` chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's/ /_/g; s/MD5_(\(.*\))_=_\(.*\)/\1 \2/'
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~$ echo 'MD5 (./x y z.jpg) = 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270' | 
 sed 's/ /_/g; s/MD5_(\(.*\))_=_\(.*\)/\1 \2/'
./x_y_z.jpg 93845ad8b6fb2797d9f1d7e0622e9270
```